# Diccionario de listas, recorrer valores Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista, diccionarios

Quiero recorrer un diccionario que tiene listas dentro

```
Lista = {'829690':['testmartin','--test$2--']}
```

Necesito que en mi funcion `For key in`... me lea `testmartin` y `--test$2--`

Acá va todo lo que tengo que hacer con la key0 y necesito que se repita lo mismo por cada key que tenga en el diccionario:

```
for lista in Lista.itervalues():
    for value in lista:
        nombre.send_keys(value)
        try:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.select2-results-dept-0'))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
        except TimeoutException:
            print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
        nombre2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.select2-results-dept-0').click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn-success:nth-child(3)').click()
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal-footer:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.modal-footer:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1)').click()
```

Answer (score 2):

No puedes usar indices sobre un diccionario porque por definición no tiene orden. Al diccionario se accede mediante sus claves:

```
for key in Lista:
    nombre.send_keys(Lista[key])
```

Si `send_keys` no recibe una lista sino que debe recibir los dos elementos de esta como argumaentos usa el operador `*` :

```
for key in Lista:
    nombre.send_keys(*Lista[key])
```

Si no va a usar la clave para nada puedes iterar sobre los valores:

- Python 2:

  ```
  for value in Lista.itervalues():
      nombre.send_keys(*value)
  ```
- Python 3:

  ```
  for value in Lista.values():
      nombre.send_keys(*value)
  ```

**Edición:**

Si necesitas llamar a la función por cada valor de la lista entonces necesitas iterar sobre ella:

```
for lista in Lista.itervalues():
    for value in lista:
        nombre.send_keys(value)
```

Comment: Me esta devolviendo los dos valores juntos: testmartin--test$2-- y necesito que lo haga por separado ya que el primer key(testmartin) realiza varias funciones luego y una vez terminadas dichas funciones quiero que llame a --test$2--

Comment: @MartinBouhier `send_kys` como debe ser llamada?. Si primero debe enviar testmartin y luego --test$2-- deberás realizar dos llamadas, una para cada argumento. `nombre.send_keys(Lista[key][0])` y `nombre.send_keys(Lista[key][1])` si siempre tiene dos elementos las lista.

Comment: no tiene ningun nombre, lo ejecuto asi en selenium. El problema es que necesito que las llamadas para cada argumento sean automaticas ya que esa lista va a tener mas de 200 elementos

Comment: Si, de esa forma puedo pero tengo miles de elementos. voy a editar tu respuesta a si me explico mejor

Comment: Edite la pregunta, hice lo que me dijiste pero me sigue pasando lo mismo, me introduce los dos valores juntos

Comment: @MartinBouhier con ese código se llama una vez por cada valor de la lista a `nombre.send_keys`. Es decir, se hace `nombre.send_keys('testmartin')`  y se ejecuta el código hasta hacer click en el primer botón, luego se llama con `nombre.send_keys('--test$2--')` se hace click en el primer botón de nuevo y luego se hace click en los otros dos.El segundo botón solo se pulsa entre una lista y otra, no entre elementos de la misma lista. Asegurate que esta es la secuencia que quieres. Si esto está bién, lo único que me se me ocurre es que el input no se limpie cada vez que se pulsa el primer botón...

Comment: ... y se concatenen entre llamadas. Prueba a hacer un `nombre.clear()` justo antes de `nombre.send_keys(value)`

Comment: Tenia un problema de espacios entre funciones. todo listo! Gracias